# Start a command on a Remotecomputer

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

how I can start the powershell-command Get-Share on a remote computer only to make a connection per RDP?

To see the events it is very easy: Get-EventLog -LogName System -Newest 5 -ComputerName SERVER01

Greetings

```
Get-Share .......
```

Comment: What do you mean by "start"? Are you not interested in the output from `Get-Share`?

Comment: Sorry for my missunderstanding headline. You are right my plan is it to start the command "Get-Share" from my computer on a remote computer.

Answer (score 0):

Some commands like "get-eventlog" have a built-in method to send the request to multiple local or remote machines, however it is not a standard to all commands.

I could not find "get-share" command documentation, to validate if it is the same case for it, however, Powershell allows a native way to send any command to a remote machine.

One of the methods is to use [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-7.3):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -Credential $Credentials -ScriptBlock {
## YOUR SCRIPT HERE ##
get-share
}
```

- You can use ComputerName Parameter to set the server name or names (can be an array of multiple server names and/or IPs)
- You can use the Credential Parameter to use credentials in case your current user do not have the needed permissions. My suggestion is not to hard-code your credentials (security risk) and if needed to use [get-credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Is is so easy - exact what I need - many thanks.

Comment: @j.Doe your welcome . Can you please set it as the accepted answer?